# Question about Common Lisp compilation order

Tags: compilation, macros, lisp, common-lisp, sbcl

I wrote a macro and a function in one file like this:

```lisp
(defun test ()
  (let ((x '(1 2 3)))
    (macro-test (x real-b)
      (print (+ 1 (car real-b))))))

(defmacro macro-test ((a b) &body body)
  `(do ((,b ,a (cdr ,b)))
       ((not ,b))
     ,@body))
```

Then I load this file in repl and run `(test)`. I got this error:

```
The variable REAL-B is unbound.
```

However, when I put `defmacro` **before** `defun`. Everything is fine.

I am confused in common lisp compilation order. I know if `defmacro` uses some functions inside, those functions should `(eval-when (:compile-toplevel :load-toplevel :execute))`, otherwise compiling will failed.

However, if macro definitions and function definitions are same in compilation time, the order is matter, right? The macro should be located in before where they are used (if I make two functions, the order doesn't matter). May I get more detail about SBCL's compiling order? And is it only for SBCL? Or in standard of Common Lisp?

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The order does always matter: when you want to use a macro, it has to be known. The macro does a source transformation. How would you be able to do that source transformation with an unknown macro?

The Common Lisp standard does not require a multi-pass compilation in such a way that first all source code is read and all macros are collected and then compilation starts from the top of the file. File compilation in Common Lisp just walks through the source code from start to end. There might be multiple compilation phases later, but that is left to the implementations...

How should Lisp compile the function `test` when the macro `macro-test` is unknown? The Lisp compiler needs a) to know that it is a macro and b) it needs to have its definition to expand the macro form.

For Common Lisp this is a basic rule:

if we have a form `(foo bar baz)` then the **evaluation** basically looks at `foo`.

1. if `foo` is a special operator -> use that special operator
2. if `foo` is a macro operator -> macro expand the code and start again
3. if `foo` is a function -> call that function with the evaluated arguments
4. else -> an error

In **compilation** it looks similar:

1. if `foo` is a special operator -> compile that special form
2. if `foo` is a macro operator -> macro expand the macro form and compile that code
3. if `foo` is a function -> compile that function form
4. else -> warn and then assume `foo` is a function and compile a call to a future function of that name

Comment: I think that file compilation is allowed (but not I think required?) to defer warnings about unknown functions until the end of the file, so that things like `(defun foo (...) ... (bar ...) ...) ... (defun bar (...) ... (foo ...) ...)` can be compiled without noise.  Certainly a compiler which did not do that would be really annoying to use!

Comment: @tfb: right, the warning in a compilation unit is there, but it will be communicated to the user at some useful time, if still necessary. In a file compilation unit, the compiler might also not directly compile the unknown function call to use late binding, but may wait for a later definition...

Comment: So, assume foo is a function is a reason why functions order looks don't matter but macro does if I understand correctly. Back to `(eval-when (:compile-toplevel))`, it means forms inside would compile before all other forms in compilation time, right?

Comment: @ccQpein: no, `(eval-when (:compile-toplevel) ...)` means that the file compiler evaluates the enclosed forms - when seen at toplevel.